# Refresh updatepanel through triggers when other updatepanel does because the first must have UpdateMode=Conditional

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, refresh, triggers

I have some updatepanels in asp.net page. I want updatepanel 2 get refreshed when updatepanel 1 does, but UpdatePanel 2 has his UpdateMode attributed set to Conditional and ChildrenAsTrigger=False, because it has another updatePanels inside and i need to control the way it is refreshed. I was trying to make a trigger for the other updatepanel but this seems not work, maybe i am missing something

Is there a way to make this happen?

If you can't figure a valid example, imagine product category list and product list, when selected category change (linkbutton inside updatepanel) product list is refreshed which is inside another updatepanel, product list change for example when you order by price (order is inside other updatepanel) and i don't want category list gets refreshed.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`updatePanelProdList.Update()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) inside the code-behind file of your page. The place to call this method in your scenario would be the event handler for the category change LinkButton.

Comment: interting, but if understand well, that will cause another postback to updatepanelProductList when the page finish his event handling. i mean first post back linkbutton event is raised updatepanel is rendered in the page and another postback for updatepanelprodList update. Is there a way to avoid this two postbacks

Comment: There is only one postback. You select a category and a postback occurs. In your event handler (server side) you call Update. The only thing that happens is that you tell ASP.NET that it should rerender the UpdatePanel. No extra postback occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that's what i am looking for! I have 2 "Update Panel" on my page, one keeping my form and other one keeping flexiGrid (non .net version,pure jQuery).

I do manual AsyncPostBack from my grid to get in edit or delete mode.

```
function doPostBackAsync(eventName, eventArgs) {
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    if (!Array.contains(prm._asyncPostBackControlIDs, eventName)) {
        prm._asyncPostBackControlIDs.push(eventName);
    }

    if (!Array.contains(prm._asyncPostBackControlClientIDs, eventName)) {
        prm._asyncPostBackControlClientIDs.push(eventName);
    }
    __doPostBack(eventName, eventArgs);
}

<a title="Edit" href="javascript:doPostBackAsync('Edit','2');">Edit</a>
```

and then i handle it like

```
string EventName = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
int EventValue = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString();
```

after determinate EventName and EventValue calling the method below

```
protected void Edit(int id)
{
    //load the form here
    UpdatePanel1.Update(); //do the trick right, without this line unable to show form fields and other stuff with newly loaded data
}
```

regards.

(sorry for my English)